# Downside to Sphinx index_sp?

Tags: indexing, sphinx, r-sp

I need to enable the index_sp (sentence and paragraph indexing feature) of Sphinx so I can perform 'Word1 SENTENCE Word2' searches i.e. ones in which two words exist in the same sentence as it is currently not working and as per the documentation for the [Sphinx Extended Query Syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html) it is a requirement for the SENTENCE operator.

However since Sphinx is so delicate in terms of matches working or not in combination of features and since it is an option not built in, I am wondering if anyone with experience with it can tell me what the possible downsides, other than size/speed of index, might be as I'm loathe to break working matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well on the case of Extended Query Syntax. You are almost certainly using it anyway. Its the only mode sphinx has (for while anyway, early versions did have mulitple query modes)
... so in itself shouldnt be scary.

Possibly the bigger issue with index_sp, its it implemented by the HTML Stripper, so need to enable html_strip=1 as well. Which might well change behaviour of queries. (if have HTML anyway!)

The only other place aware that index_sp might affect things is 'cross sentence phrase matches'.

Without index_sp, a query like "one two" would match text [one. two], but with index_sp it wouldnt. Ie the . has split into sentances, so no longer match "phrase" wise. This can be a good thing, but is a change.
This can in some cases affect things that are not really sentance seperators. Eg the . can break up sentances, when its not really a full stop. Sphinx as a relatively good algorithm for braking sentances, but not perfect.

Comment: Thanks you for that heads-up. Stripping HTML would likely mess up a bunch of other pattern matches I have. I will make a secondary index and just apply this html stripper index_sp and see how far I get with that thanks